# How to merge mesh with particles to skeletal mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature, particles

Excuse me but I am honestly very frustrated at this and I spent hours trying to make it work, but it's hopeless, and I don't understand why there isn't any tutorials for it!?

I have created a character mesh which moves with an armature. I also created a separate mesh that has hair particles and it serves as the eyebrows for the character. All I want to do is stick those eye brows to the character, as simple as that sounds. It seems impossible to do...

I tried parenting, did not work... if I merge them together, the particles get completely messed up.

Is there a solution for this at all?

Comment: Once you've joined the eyebrows object to the head, select all its vertices, remove them from all groups (down arrow button on the right of the Vertex Groups list) and assign them to the good vertex group?